# Changing jQuery based on screensize

Tags: jquery, screen, responsive-design, truncate

I'm currently using a small plugin (jTruncate) that truncates text when it's over a certain threshold of letters - and I was wondering, can I tie that letter threshold to the screen size?

For example

if screensize under <320 px - show 45 Letters

if screensize under <500 px - show 60 Letters

```
$().ready(function() {  
    $('#recent').jTruncate
    ({  
        length: 45,
        moreText: [""],
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as an alternative to Javascript, you could use a CSS media query and wrap the last 15 chars in a span which is hidden in the smaller resolution.

Comment: That seems like an incredibly 'hacky' way of doing things tbh, and sadly, I don't think that'll be suitable (although slightly ingenious) as the content that is being truncated is going to be dynamic - Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: @Ollie no this is actually the better way to do it. the CSS rendering will be magnitudes faster than anything JS can do (moot point), and media-queries are defiantly good for this type of operation. Also having it 'dynamic' makes no difference as the CSS will apply to the container and not the content.

Comment: I take back what I said completely then!
If you haven't noticed, I'm new to this - and already I'm spewing rubbish :) 
So sorry about that - thank-you so much for your assistance, I'll see if I can do it with media-queries

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/EwNxR/8/ here is a demo with js. However I do suggest using media-queries as Jimbo noted in his answer.

Important things to note in the code:
1) You will likely want to listen for page resize and action on it. There is no point in running the code once on page load then not when the user resizes their browser window.
2) You shouldn't have to use the jQuery $(window).height() if IE6 is not a concern. Use window.innerHeight.

```
window.onresize = resizer;
function resizer() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
        $('#recent').jTruncate({
            length: 45,
            moreText: [""],
        });
    }
}
```

I'm not 100% familiar with the plugin, however if the options are structured like jQuery plugins generally are you should be able to initialize it on page load then just change the length value.

```
var recent = $('#recent'),
    defaultLength = 256; // default, can be whatever.
window.onresize = resizer;
recent.jTruncate({ length: defaultLength, moreText: [""] });
function resizer() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
        recent.jTruncate("length", 45); // don't re-init the plugin, just change the option.
    } else {
        recent.jTruncate("length", defaultLength); // page resized and truncating is no longer needed to be shorter.
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly those little snippets didn't work for me, thank-you for trying though - damn sight better than what I could do.

Is there anyway you could write one example of css wrapping/hiding? I can't find anything on it (although, to be fair, I'm more than likely looking in completely the wrong places)

http://jsfiddle.net/zvHwq/3/

Comment: @Ollie that little thank you at the end is annoying. Sorry. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wHcxk/) is a very short very limited pure css example. Note: You should use a mix of css and javascript for this. javascript mainly to apply a css class rule to an element when the more is clicked and remove the class when less is clicked.

Answer (score -3):

Just use `window`.

```
var win_width = $(window).width();
var win_height = $(window).height();
```